# Progress Dialog not showing on Google Glass

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-gdk

I have a basic progress dialog call in an async class for a google glass app. I implemented it and it did not throw any errors, but also did not show up in any way on Glass. I then tried the program in a Galaxy Nexus emulator and it worked perfectly. Is there a resolution or compatibility issue that keeps progress dialog from appearing on Glass? Here is my code just in case I'm a dummy.

```
    public class GetUPC extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{       

    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();   
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx_context);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
                this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        //secret stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try
        {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Post_ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are working with Glass? Guessing you're using the Immersion concept and creating an Activity...Are you sure your AsyncTask is running? How are you going out displaying the Activity on Glass? Also it's not necessary to call the super methods of AsyncTask (e.g. super.onPreExecute() is unnecessary).

Comment: Try - https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar